# Partial converse of the fact: $f\in L^p , g\in L^q \Rightarrow fg\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Hölder's inequality says If $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$ and $ f\in L^p, g\in L^q$, then $fg\in L^1$.

Then how about the following converse:

> Let $g$ be measurable. If for all $f\in L^p$ we have $fg \in L^1$, then is $g\in L^q$?

I guess this may not be true. But I guess there exist a condition that makes this true. Am I right? If  there exist such condition, can you explain it?

Comment: result is true whenever $1\leq p<\infty$. Use uniform boundedness principle and the fact that for all such $p$ we have $(L^p)^* = L^q$.

Comment: Does Uniform boundedness principle mean banach theorem?

Comment: Yes Banach steinhauss theorem.

Comment: I have not yet learned the theorem. Could you explain more specipically?

Comment: 277793 Take a look at the book "Real analysis -modern techniques and their application" by Folland. Look at the chapter 6, section 6.2, theorem 6.14.

Answer (score 1):

The theory of $L^p$ spaces is usually developed over spaces with a $\sigma$-finite measure. In this case the result is true: see [Discontinuous functionals on $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1008990)

For general measures this is not true, as David C. Ullrich demonstrated by an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1586063):

> Let $X=\{0\}$, with the unique $\sigma$-algebra. Define $\mu$ by $\mu(X)=\infty$. Let $g(0)=1$. Then $gf\in L^1$ for every $f\in L^p$, simply because $f\in L^p$ implies $f=0$. But $g\notin L^q$.